# Restrict to capture screenshot and do not allow to show the application window while scree sharing in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0, screenshot, screensharing

I need to restrict to capture screenshot and do not allow to show the application window while scree sharing from my WPF application with .Net 6. It is working fine except with the combobox options.
[image]

I have done with SetWindowDisplayAffinity and it is working fine. But while taking a screenshot or screen share I can see the combobox options. How we can restrict these things? Here is my code snippet which I have used.

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr hWnd, uint dwAffinity);
    public const int WDA_NONE = 0x00000000;
    public const int WDA_MONITOR = 0x00000001;
    public const int WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE = 0x00000011;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindowHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
        const uint WDA_NONE = 0;
        const uint WDA_MONITOR = 1;
        SetWindowDisplayAffinity(mainWindowHandle, WDA_MONITOR);
    }
```